# How to add a permission to a login if it doesn't have it in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, security, authentication, permissions

I have two logins `login1` and `login2`. `login1` has `sysadmin` server role and I want to grant `login2` some permissions conditionally under the context of `login1`.

After some googling I found the function `HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME` can be used to test if a user (current user) has some permission. So I wrote the following code:

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'login2';
IF HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(NULL, NULL, 'VIEW DEFINITION') != 1
    GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO login2;

IF HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(NULL, NULL, 'VIEW SERVER STATE') != 1
    GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO login2;
REVERT;
```

But I got the following error when I executed it:

```
Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.
```

That's reasonable, because I'm granting permissions under the context of `login2`, which is not correct. So I modified my code as:

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'login2';
IF HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(NULL, NULL, 'VIEW DEFINITION') != 1
BEGIN
    REVERT;
    GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO login2;
END

EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'login2';
IF HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(NULL, NULL, 'VIEW SERVER STATE') != 1
BEGIN
    REVERT;
    GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO login2;
END
```

But still I got the exactly same error message when I executed it. Anyone can help to point me the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Try `execute as user = 'login2'` not `as login`

Answer (score 1):

```sql
CREATE TABLE #temp (permission VARCHAR(20))

EXECUTE AS USER = 'login2';  

INSERT INTO #temp SELECT permission_name FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') WHERE permission_name = 'VIEW DEFINITION';  

REVERT
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #temp)
    GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO login2;

DROP TABLE #temp
GO

CREATE TABLE #temp (permission VARCHAR(20))

EXECUTE AS USER = 'login2';  

INSERT INTO #temp SELECT permission_name FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') WHERE permission_name = 'VIEW SERVER STATE';  

REVERT
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #temp)
    GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO login2;

DROP TABLE #temp
```